# Kivy: Popup is blocked by main thread

Tags: python, kivy

My Kivy app has a button whose callback involves a `UrlRequest`. I'd like to provide a popup that askes the user to wait while the request is being completed. The problem is that executing the request itself blocks the popup from coming up. I've tried placing the `open()` method of the popup at different places with no luck. In the following example, the popup is opened in the `on_progress()` callback of the `UrlRequest`:

```
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import urllib

kv = '''
<ScreenTemplate@SignUpScreen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (0.09,0.65,0.8)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Button:
        size_hint: .3, .2
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5,'center_y': .25}
        text: 'Call Request'
#         on_press: app.p.open()
        on_release: app.callback1()
    Label:
        text: 'This is ' +  root.name
        font_size: '50sp'

<MyNavDrawer>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: .25
        pos_hint: {'center_y':.5}
        Button:
            text: 'Screen 1'
            on_press: app.callback2( 'screen1')
        Button:
            text: 'Screen 2'
            on_press: app.callback2('screen2')    
    SMRoot:

<SMRoot>:
    ScreenTemplate:
        name: 'screen1'            

    ScreenTemplate:
        name: 'screen2'    
'''

Builder.load_string(kv)
class SMRoot(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    pass

class myNavDrawer(NavigationDrawer):
    pass

class myApp(App):

    popup_opened = False
    p=Popup(title="Posting request...",
            content=Label(text="... Please wait"),
            size=(100, 100),
            size_hint=(0.5, 0.5),
            auto_dismiss = False)
    def build(self):
        self.mynavdrawer = myNavDrawer()
        return self.mynavdrawer

    def on_success(self, req, results):
        print 'In on_success: '+ results
        self.p.title = 'Success'
        self.p.content = Label(text=results)
        self.p.auto_dismiss = True
        popup_opened = False


    def on_failure(self, req, results):
        self.p.title = 'Failure'
        self.p.content = Label(text=results)
        print 'In on_failure: '+ results
        self.p.auto_dismiss = True

    def on_error(self, req, results):
        self.p.title = 'Error'
        self.p.content = Label(text=results.strerror)
        print  'In on_error: '+ results.strerror
        self.p.auto_dismiss = True    

    def on_progress (self, req, results, chunk):
        if not self.popup_opened:
            print 'In on_progress: '+ str(results)
            self.p.open()
            self.popup_opened = True   


    def callback1(self):
        params={'show_env':'1'}
        params = urllib.urlencode(params)
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                   'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'
        req = UrlRequest(url,
                         self.on_success,
                         req_body = params,
                         req_headers = headers, 
                         on_failure=self.on_failure, 
                         on_error=self.on_error,
                         on_progress=self.on_progress, 
                         timeout=4)
        req.wait()
        print 'After UrlRequest'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    myApp().run()
```

Running this causes the popup to appear *after* the request is completed, which defeats the purpose.

Notice the commented `on_press: app.p.open()` binding in the Button under `<ScreenTemplate@SignUpScreen>`. This works perfectly, except that it's a workaround that is far from ideal. I'd like the popup to be opened anytime the `UrlRequest` is sent; the above workaround has to be applied to every button.

Any ideas on how to open the button from the main thread while the callback is running would be appreciated. I've tried using `Clock.schedule_once()` as well. From the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html), it seems `EventDispatcher.dispatch()` might do the trick, but I don't know what event to dispatch.

Comment: It's funny because I have the opposite problem, i want to popup a synchronous question box in kivy

Answer (score 1):

I think this line:

```
  req.wait()
```

blocks you on the main thread.
remove it. you can also open the popup sooner - instead of the *req.wait()*

That being said, you can replicate this behavior using **delayable** (from [kivyoav](https://github.com/yglazner/kivyoav/blob/master/examples/e_delayable.py))

```
@delayable
def callback1(self):
    ...
    while not reg.is_finished:
        yield 0.02 # sleep for 20 ms...

    ... #req is ready now...
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of *kivyoav*

Comment: The `wait()` indeed blocks the thread. However, I'm migrating existing code from the synchronous Requests library to the asynchronous UrlRequest. I was hoping that in the interim, I could use the `wait()` so as to not break things. I guess that may simply not be possible, due to [this known issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/ERcZDjr3znE).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you do. The `UrlRequest` takes place in the main thread. This means that the UI won't be updated unless the main thread is allowed to run, because it's blocked inside the `callback1` function.
What you want to do is create a new thread for the `UrlRequest`
Try using `Threading`

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem using threads. Any other attempts finished up the GIL blocking the popup to show or showing it after the operating method. I use `def showTheMessage(self):` when I want a popup to show until the method in the other thread is done.

```
# main screen
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name="MAIN SCREEN"
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
# popup class  
class MsgBox(Popup):
    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(MsgBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj

# app class
class MyApp(App):

    def step1(self):
        # start the method in a thread
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = self.yourBelowedMethod)
        t1.start()
        t1.join()
        # dismiss the message popup once finished
        self.popupMsg.dismiss()

    def step2(self, *args):
        # set the popup structure
        self.popupMsg = MsgBox(self)
        # run the activity popup in a thread
        t3 = threading.Thread(target = self.popupMsg.open)
        t3.start()
        t3.join()

    def showTheMessage(self):
        # call step2 and step1
        self.step2()    # call the message popup
        self.step1()    # call the method

    def build(self):
        sm = Builder.load_string("""
    
ScreenManager
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    MainScreen:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        auto_dismiss: False
        title: "MainScreenTitle"
        title_align: "center"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            Label:
                text: "MainScreenLabel"
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                spacing: 10
                size_hint: 1, .8
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                spacing: 10
                size_hint: 1, .2
                Button:
                    font_size: 50
                    text: "MessageButtonExit"  # exit app
                    on_press:
                        self.background_color = 0,255,0,1
                        app.exit()

<MsgBox>:
    size_hint: 1, .7
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "yourTitle"       
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: "yourText"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
""")

        return sm
```